# What is the difference between the X-ray diffraction and neutron diffraction?

Tags: solid-state-physics, diffraction, neutrons, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

In the Kittel book, I have read that the ionic form of $\text{KCl}$ contains $\text{K}^+$ and $\text{Cl}^-$, having equal number of electrons. Looking at the statement in figure that while doing the XRD, the crystal looks to be simple cubic but looking at the diagram it is FCC.

[image]

Now if XRD will not be able to correctly judge the structure then which method we are going to use?

Comment: Wikipedia seems to address the difference between x-ray and neutron diffraction head on: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_diffraction

Comment: The first few pages of [Introduction to neutron scattering](https://www.ncnr.nist.gov/staff/hammouda/distance_learning/chapter_6.pdf).